# Show AWS API Gateway Cloudwatch Logs in Web Application ( without login to AWS console)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

### Problem Statement:

As a admin user I want to see who accessed application and what actions did.

### Expected Solution :

All the application REST API calls is configured in AWS API Gateway and enabled Cloudwatch logs

AWS cloud watch logs is accessible by login to AWS console and track all the requests.

But I want to see those logs in my application in a data grid showing with some filters

is there a way to get AWS cloud watch logs through API call by passing some conditions ( like user, date, status) ?

If YES - Please help with some samples

Comment: You can use the Cloudwatch SDK to get the information you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what programming language you are using for your REST API, you would want to include the AWS SDK dependency and use something like [`FilterLogEvents`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatchLogs/latest/APIReference/API_FilterLogEvents.html).